# fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value (lldb)

Tags: swift

I have a table view with cells. When I press the cell it does not show the second view controller and when I press another cell, it gives me this error:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
>   (lldb)

This is my code:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if segue.identifier == "toMediaPlayer" {

        let VC = segue.destinationViewController as! UIViewController
        let indexPath: NSIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!

        VC.title = songs[indexPath.row]


    }
```

Comment: this error occurs always when an optional value is nil while being unwrapped, so either `destinationViewController` or `indexPathForSelectedRow()` is nil

Comment: how can I correct that >??

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend to use `indexPathForCell()` rather than `indexPathForSelectedRow()` to get the index path. The appropriate cell is passed as the `sender` parameter

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

  if segue.identifier == "toMediaPlayer" {
    if sender is UITableViewCell {
      let VC = segue.destinationViewController as! UIViewController
      let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForCell(sender)

      VC.title = songs[indexPath.row]
    }
}
```

I doubt that the error occurs in the line to get the destinationViewController